# How to use Selenium to select an option from a React JS drop down with div tag/class?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have tried all the possible things. also, tried searching over tried different combinations and variations. I can get the element clicked which opens the dropdown. but i am not able to select an option in it. I tried with actions, sendkeys, keys.down/enter and multiple things as well. however, it didn't help. That's the only thing I am stuck on.

```
//selecting office

driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).click();

// attempt with actions
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="DG5QEPn"]/div/div/div1/div1"))).click();

// attempt with sendKeys
driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).sendKeys("RTP HQ"); 

// attempt with Keys.Down and Keys.Enter
driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).sendKeys(Keys.Down); 
driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

[image]

Comment: It will be good if you give HTML DOM code instead of screenshot

Comment: <div class="css-fx5u20 react-select__value-container react-select__value-container--has-value"><div class="css-o6m1t9-singleValue react-select__single-value">RTP HQ</div><div class="css-1g6gooi"><div class="react-select__input" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="select_input_Office" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-

Comment: Please add this in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me

WebElement selectMyElement = driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn"));

selectMyElement.click();

Thread.sleep(4000);

Actions keyDown = new Actions(driver);
keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN, Keys.ENTER)).perform();

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Whereas just doing selectMyElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN); over and over did not work. You need to create the Action and use the Keys.chord. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javascript click which will click on the element given it is present unlike the webdriver selenium click which needs the element to be displayed first.

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: This only works with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SDETRahulJain/ReactDriverCSharp.git Help to locate control in react based application with Selenium & C#

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how the github repository you linked can help the OP

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.